# Querying REDIS with HMSET

Tags: database, data-structures, redis, node-redis

I am using REDIS data store and I have created HMSET like:

```
HMSET key:1 source 5 target 2
HMSET key:2 source 3 target 1
HMSET key:3 source 3 target 5
HMSET key:4 source 6 target 2
HMSET key:5 source 2 target 3
```

Now, I want to query these keys based on the provided source and target list. Suppose, the list of source and target is [2, 3, 6]

I want to have a query like

```
select from key where source in[2, 3, 6] and traget in[2, 3, 6]
```

which will give me the result like

```
key:4 source 6 target 2 
key:5 source 2 target 3
```

Comment: Your question is very much specific to redis. And there's no node code in the question. So all tags except `[redis]` are irrelevant, please remove them to not pollute people's question feeds.

Comment: I am using node-redis as a client to execute the same code. I think that it make sense to add node-redis as a tag.

Comment: Not sure it adds much value. node-redis allows you to execute the full range of redis commands, I assume? If so, it doesn't add any information to the question.

Answer (score 3):

With a dataset like this (only a few sets), your only option is to iterate them (either in a lua script or by fetching into the app) and do the filtering yourself by inspecting the hashes.

To speed things up, you could maintain the secondary indexes (again, the effort is yours). Something like:

```
SADD source:3 key:2 key:3
SADD target:2 key:1 key:4
```

Then you can relatively quickly find all matching keys by issuing `SINTERSTORE` command

```
SINTERSTORE found_keys source:2 source:3 source:6 target:2 target:3 target:6
```

You'll have the keys you seek under the `found_keys` name.

Although, if you find yourself do *this*, you should ask yourself: why don't I just give up and use an SQL-capable database, because I clearly want one.

Comment: We are migrating a write intensive module from mongodb to redis for temporary data storage. There is a read query in mongo which I wanted to convert into redis, so that I achieve the same result with minimal change. Anyway, thanks for your response.